# To execute a method at specific time interval in form

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows application in C# with ten forms. I have a method in a form. I need this method to be executed at specific time intervals. How can I achieve it? Pls help?

Comment: Use Timer to invoke your method time by time

Comment: Use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Comment: @Habib: Your comment is also not complete and deserve a full answer as there  is no single Timer in .net and multiple options are possible , please either move it to proper answer or remove incomplete comment!

Comment: @Saurabh, its a comment :), not an answer, just a link to help out the OP, I haven't put the comment to earn some rep.

Comment: @Habib: I am also not the repo Hungary its the genuine feedback , i just don't understand why ppl come to the answer and downvote it without writing the reason. I don't need it , it just the community contribution which i want to contribute to the fellow developers.

Comment: @Habib : FYI ... i removed the answer and i think what ever be the repo it generates will be rolledback

Answer (score -1):

Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer class.

You can get the detail and example at MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

However, I think there are already many threads like this.

Comment: Don't only reference to a website, websites can go down and then this topic would be of no use anymore, provide an example for the questioner please.